# Temporary model field in kohana 2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

i have a question about kohana 2:

I need to create a temporary field on every find(), called 'slug'. This field will have a dynamically created "SEO friendly" url of current record.

For example, the site adress is www.domain.com and i want to view a post with id 6 called "This is an example title". The desired slug will be: `1-this-is-an-example-title`

I don't want to generate the slug directly in view by echoing `$post->id . '-' . url::title($post->title)`. What i want to achieve is an ability to echo a dynamically created variable `$post->slug` which will not be presented in database, it'll just be generated in a model.

I hope you understand me well ?
Can you provide me any ideas or code samples please?

Big thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected $_slug = NULL;

public function __get($name)
{
   if ($name == 'slug')
   {
      if ($this->_loaded AND $this->_slug === NULL )
      {
         $this->_slug = $this->pk().'-'.url::title($this->title);
      }
      return $this->_slug;
   }
   return parent::__get($name);
}
```

Comment: Big thanks for this! Works great :) Just one thing, there should be `$this->loaded` instead of `$this->_loaded`

Comment: ORM has `$this->loaded()` (method) and `$this->_loaded` (property) :)